# MQJE018: Protocol error - unexpected segment type received

Tags: java, websphere, message-queue, messaging

Calling all MQ Gurus,

I have a box under my desk which we use to replicate our production environment which is:

WebSphere 6.1
Fedora Linux
MQ 6.0

Whenever one of our applications tries to send a message to a MQ queue we get the following error: MQJE018: Protocol error - unexpected segment type received

Any suggestions on what this might mean would be appreciated, stack traces are below.

```
Dump of callerThis =
Object type = com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBListenerImpl
com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBListenerImpl@744c744c

==> Performing default dump from com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSDiagnosticModule  = Wed May 06 13:09:58 BST 2009
Dump of callerThis =
Object type = com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBListenerImpl
com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBListenerImpl@744c744c

Linked exception = com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2195
MQJE018: Protocol error - unexpected segment type received
        at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:238)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:318)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:338)
        at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:84)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:168)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:774)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:690)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:646)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:153)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:544)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQSPIQueueManager.<init>(MQSPIQueueManager.java:69)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.createQM(MQConnection.java:2401)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.createQMXA(MQConnection.java:1783)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection.<init>(MQQueueConnection.java:110)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection.<init>(MQQueueConnection.java:67)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnection.<init>(MQXAQueueConnection.java:57)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnectionFactory.createXAQueueConnection(MQXAQueueConnectionFactory.java:80)
```

EDIT:I have looked up the reason codes in the IBM documentation which gives little help

```
2195 (X'0893')
MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR
Explanation:

The call was rejected because an unexpected error occurred.
Completion Code:

MQCC_FAILED
Programmer Response:

Check the application's parameter list to ensure, for example, that the correct number of parameters was passed, and that data pointers and storage keys are valid. If the problem cannot be resolved, contact your system programmer.

    * On z/OS, check whether any information has been displayed on the console. If this error occurs on an MQCONN or MQCONNX call, check that the subsystem named is an active MQ subsystem. In particular, check that it is not a DB2(TM) subsystem. If the problem cannot be resolved, rerun the application with a CSQSNAP DD card (if you have not already got a dump) and send the resulting dump to IBM.
    * On OS/2 and i5/OS, consult the FFST record to obtain more detail about the problem.
    * On HP OpenVMS, Compaq NonStop Kernel, and UNIX systems, consult the FDC file to obtain more detail about the problem.
```

Comment: Is the problem resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, finally managed to get around this error. It was nothing to do with the MQ install its self. I knew it was some kind of network issue so I changed the host name settings within websphere from the hostname to the ip of the box and everything worked fine.

Note, I made the host name changes on the queues and on the queue connection factories.

Hope that helps someone.

Karl